# Node stream pipeline stops prematurely

Tags: node.js, sockets, stream

Think of this piece of code as a relay between a NAT-ted service (`input`) and an external service (`output`) that wants to communicate with the `input`.

This relay is on a public server and opens two ports in order to relay:

- port `4040` where `input` connects and forwards the TCP traffic from target service
- port `4041` where some external client connects to the relay

The relay should pipe what it receives from `input` on port `4040` to the external client on port `4041`.

I can see both services connecting to the relay but the data flow just stops after, what I suspect the output socket closing. In the following example I used a `stream.pipeline` but I also tried with simple `.pipe` directly on the sockets with same results

import net from "net"
import stream from "stream";

```
export default () => {
    const inputServer = net.createServer();
    const outputServer = net.createServer();

    inputServer.listen(4040, "0.0.0.0", () => {
        console.log('TCP Server is running on port ' + 4040 + '.');
    });

    outputServer.listen(4041, "0.0.0.0", () => {
        console.log('TCP Server is running on port ' + 4041 + '.');
    });

    let inSocket = null;
    inputServer.on('connection', (sock) => {
        inSocket = sock;
    });

    outputServer.on('connection', (sock) => {
        if (inSocket) {
            stream.pipeline(inSocket, sock, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('Pipeline failed.', err);
                } else {
                    console.log('Pipeline succeeded.');
                }
            })

            stream.pipeline(sock, inSocket, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('Pipeline failed.', err);
                } else {
                    console.log('Pipeline succeeded.');
                }
            })
        }
    });
}
```

My goal is to keep an open socket to the input service and relay with any output will connect.

Answer (score 0):

> data flow just stops after, what I suspect the output socket closing

`pipeline` or `.pipe()` will automatically close the output stream when the input stream ends so it won't keep your input stream open for successive input stream connections.

Using `.pipe()`, you can override that behavior by passing an option:

```
inSocket.pipe(sock, {end: false});
```

and

```
sock.pipe(inSocket, {end: false});
```

You will then need some separate error handling for each stream as `.pipe()` doesn't do as complete error handling as `pipeline()` does.

In this way, you let each stream close itself when the client chooses rather than having the server close it when a given streaming operation is complete.

I don't see a similar option for `pipeline()`.

I'm also curious how you plan to use this.  Do you intend for there to be one  long connected `inSocket` and many separate connections to the outputServer?  Do you intend or need more than one outputServer connection at once?  Or just one at at time.  Since you're not auto destroying, I wonder if you need to do some manual cleanup (unpiping, for example) when any socket disconnects?  `.pipe()` is also famous for not unwinding all its event listeners which can sometimes lead to GC issues if you don't manually clean up things properly.